# Read a sequence of words from input. Use "Quit" to terminate, print in order they were entered and don't print a word twice.

Tags: c++

It would be great if someone can provide a better code than mine, in spite of working it also sucks. Also, there is a problem with my code!! When I print my new array `arr`, in output the positions of array is skipped when there is a duplicate word, and it outputs an empty space for that.

For example:

```
bat,
cat,
mat,
       //here the word bat is not printed again, but instead i get an empty space
rat,
quit,
```

Also please only use pointers, array or strings, because I have yet to study vectors, lists, maps and such. Thank you.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string word[100];
    string arr[100];
    int i=0,j,k,m,n;

    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"enter word: \n";
        cin>>word[i];
        if(word[i]=="quit")  
        break;
        i++;
    } 

    for(j=i,m=0;j>=0,m<=i;m++)
    {                     
        for(k=j-1;k>=0;k--)
        {
            if(word[j] == word[k])
            goto start;                         
        }   

        arr[m]=word[j];                                                              
        start:
        j--;                                       
     }                                                 

     for(n=m;n>0;n--)
         cout<<arr[n]<<"\n";                                           

     getch();
 }
```

Comment: This might be better asked on [codereview.se].

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read the
[faq]. You'll get a [badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges) (c:

Comment: @PeterWood: Code Review is for code that _works_.

Comment: I can't reproduce any problem, the code works well. 
It gets words until "quit" then prints out them. What the problem again?

Comment: @Mat Sorry, I read only the first sentence.

Comment: no, the problem is that when it encounters a previous encountered word, it doesn't prints it(that is what it is supposed to do), but instead it gives an empty space for it, and i don't want that.I don't want the empty space.

Comment: How do you enter the words? I enter a word them press Enter and ...

Comment: ya even i press enter after every word. Try entering these strings. bat,cat,bat,mat and quit.  you will get an empty space for the second bat.

Comment: @DhruvKhatkar: use a `std::(unordered_)set` rather than two old-style arrays, you'll get de-duplication for "free".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed a little, I didn't wanted to spend time to understand your `for(j=i,m=0;j>=0,m<=i;m++)` cycle so fully rewrited it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string word[100];
    string arr[100];
    int wordCount = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"enter word: \n";
        cin>>word[wordCount];
        if(word[wordCount] == "quit")
        {  
            break;
        }
        ++wordCount;
    } 

    int arrCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < wordCount; ++i)
    {                  
        bool found = false;   
        for (int j = 0; j < arrCount; ++j)
        {
            if (arr[j] == word[i])
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            arr[arrCount] = word;
            ++arrCount;
        }
    }                                                 

    for(int i = 0; i < arrCount; ++i)
    {
        cout<<arr[n]<<"\n";
    }

    getch();
}
```

And **never use goto**, your teatcher will be very angry if he see it.

Comment: IHMO it would be better to insert `break;` after `found = true;`